# Beginner's Error in python, How can I fix this 'lat' of type <class 'str'> is not convertible to float

Tags: python, string, maps, data-science

I have recently been using python and I am doing a job using Foursquare and data obtained from wikipedia. I am trying to make a map with the following code:

```
    venues_map = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=13) # generate map centred of Ciutat Vella

# add a red circle marker to represent the center of the neighborhoods 
folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker(
    ['lat','lng'],
    radius=10,
    color='red',
    popup='Eixample',
    fill = True,
    fill_color = 'red',
    fill_opacity = 0.6
).add_to(venues_map)

# add the shops as blue circle markers
for lat, lng, label in zip(new_df.lat, new_df.lng, new_df.categories):
    folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker(
        [lat,lng],
        radius=5,
        color='blue',
        popup=label,
        fill = True,
        fill_color='blue',
        fill_opacity=0.6
    ).add_to(venues_map)

# display map
venues_map
```

When executing the line I get the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/utilities.py in validate_location(location)
     58         try:
---> 59             float(coord)
     60         except (TypeError, ValueError):

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'lat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-7a61c4e1c46b> in <module>
     11     fill = True,
     12     fill_color = 'red',
---> 13     fill_opacity = 0.6
     14 ).add_to(venues_map)
     15 

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/vector_layers.py in __init__(self, location, radius, popup, tooltip, **kwargs)
    303     def __init__(self, location, radius=10, popup=None, tooltip=None, **kwargs):
    304         super(CircleMarker, self).__init__(location, popup=popup,
--> 305                                            tooltip=tooltip)
    306         self._name = 'CircleMarker'
    307         self.options = path_options(line=False, radius=radius, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/map.py in __init__(self, location, popup, tooltip, icon, draggable, **kwargs)
    275         super(Marker, self).__init__()
    276         self._name = 'Marker'
--> 277         self.location = validate_location(location)
    278         self.options = parse_options(
    279             draggable=draggable or None,

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/utilities.py in validate_location(location)
     61             raise ValueError('Location should consist of two numerical values, '
     62                              'but {!r} of type {} is not convertible to float.'
---> 63                              .format(coord, type(coord)))
     64         if math.isnan(float(coord)):
     65             raise ValueError('Location values cannot contain NaNs.')

ValueError: Location should consist of two numerical values, but 'lat' of type <class 'str'> is not convertible to float.
```

I have looked and the LAT column if it is a float, I don't know how to fix it and I can't move forward. I would appreciate any help.

The value of Lat comes from the following table, in which it shows the name of the neighborhoods of Barcelona and shows its latitude and longitude to be able to take from there the values to form the map:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeMsu.png)

Comment: can you paste the value of lat here please :)

Comment: it looks like you are trying to pass in "lat" as a string to a field that wants to get a float value

Comment: folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker(
    ['lat','lng'] here you have "lat" and "lng" which means you are passing in 2 strings

Comment: maybe you wanted to do [lat,lng] assuming you have set these variables earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker(
    ['lat','lng'],
    radius=10,
    color='red',
    popup='Eixample',
    fill = True,
    fill_color = 'red',
    fill_opacity = 0.6
).add_to(venues_map)
```

You are trying to pass in a tuple of strings.

Reading the documentation : https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html

> location (tuple[float, float]) – Latitude and Longitude pair (Northing, Easting)

The location tuple takes two floats. Try to remove the "" from lat and lng and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not fallen into that detail. I have been able to generate the map !!